# Is it possible to show the bookmarks bar only in the home page using firefox?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

This is the standard behaviour in Google Chrome: unless otherwise specified, the bookmarks bar is visible only when in the home page, and disappears as soon as a web site is opened. This makes a lot of sense to me because I may want to see my bookmarks in the home page, but once I selected a site the bar becomes needless and wastes space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install this addon

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hide-bookmarksbar/